# how can I use PNML Framework to parse pnml file?

Tags: xml, frameworks, petri-net

I try to find how can I use PNML Framework  http://pnml.lip6.fr/index.html to parse pnml file but I didn't find any useful information, can you help me?

Answer (score 1):

PNML framework is a library of Java classes. You can build a project using the library and interact with it via its API.

If you have specific needs like PNML validation, you can use some of the tools built using the PNML framework without programming anything in Java.

To begin development with PNML Framework you should start by reading the Basic Tutorial ([wiki](https://srcdev.lip6.fr/trac/research/ISOIEC-15909/wiki/English/User/Tutorial)) and, if you are using Eclipse, install PNML framework to work with the IDE ([wiki](https://srcdev.lip6.fr/trac/research/ISOIEC-15909/wiki/English/User/InstallPFW2)).

More details can be found in the remaining volumes of user documentation ([table of contents](https://srcdev.lip6.fr/trac/research/ISOIEC-15909/wiki/English/User)).

Comment: thanks, I want to change validation code by adding new code to generate java files represent pnml file. can this framework help me to do so? I find that the responsible class of validation is 
[[com.thaiopensource.validate.ValidationDriver;]]
but I couldn't discover how can I modify it to do what I need.